# Añadir "en la misma pregunta" a la primera categoría de preguntas no pertinentes

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, traducciones

En la página de [¿Sobré qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) se incluye una lista de temas que, aunque relacionados con la programación y la informática, no se consideran pertinentes en este sitio. La lista no es tan extensa como la de la [versión inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) porque no existen otros sitios en la red de StackExchange en español que sí existen en inglés. Lo cual está bien... pero hay un cambio que considero significativo en uno de los puntos comunes y que debería añadirse a nuestro sitio.

En la versión inglesa, en el primer punto, pone que en los casos en los que se busque ayuda con depuración debe incluirse el código necesario para reproducir el fallo "en la misma pregunta" (negrita para resaltar esa parte):

> Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:
>
> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

En cambio en la versión de SOes, esa parte de "en la misma pregunta" no se incluye:

> Algunas preguntas no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías mencionadas anteriormente:
>
> 1. Preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración ("¿por qué no funciona este código?") deben incluir cual es el comportamiento deseado, un problema o error específico y el mínimo de código necesario para reproducirlo. Las preguntas sin una clara enunciación del problema no son útiles para otros usuarios. Ver: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

¿Por qué no está esa parte en nuestro sitio? ¿Es una decisión tomada a conciencia o ha sido algo que se ha perdido con la traducción? Si es lo primero: ¿por qué?; si es lo segundo, ¿podría incluirse en el texto?

Answer (score 2):

Estrictamente no debería hacer falta ("Las preguntas (...) deben incluir (...)" ya es lo bastante explícito), pero ya que está en el texto original lo he añadido a la versión traducida.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo una explicación del motivo por el que no se incluye **"en la misma pregunta"**, pero dejo mi aporte... Traducido desde Google Traductor y mejorado.

> Algunas preguntas siguen siendo fuera de tema, incluso si encajan en una de las categorías enumeradas anteriormente:
>
> 1. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda de depuración ("¿Por qué no funciona este código?") deben incluir el comportamiento deseado, un problema o error específico y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo **en la pregunta en sí**. Las preguntas sin una declaración clara del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Ver: [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Que el Google traductor lo haya incluido significa que el que tradujo eso es un humano, capaz de cometer errores como ese.